# alternative to connect using redux hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have used useDisptach and useStore hooks to access the dispatch and state. But it doesn't seem to work unless i use connect. Is there a way to use connect using hooks?
So basically my question is:

Is there any alternative to this line, using redux hooks:

```
export default connect()(component);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector-examples) to get the only specific value from the store.

Something like below

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const CounterComponent = () => {
  const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter)
  return <div>{counter}</div>
}

export default CounterComponent;
```

I have created a react context API example similar to the redux store. Check stackblitz link, It'll help you to understand useDisptatch, useSelector, and connect function. Might not the same implementation as the react-redux package, but works similarly.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactjs-usecontext-usereducer-state-management

Comment: Maybe i didn't put it out correctly, but i just wanted to know that while using redux hooks like useDisptatch , useSelector etc., should we 'export default Component' or 'export default connect()(Component)'? Few moments ago simply exporting the component i.e 'export default Compoonent' was not working. So i exported the connect()(component) and it worked. But now when i resorted back to exporting the component alone i.e 'export default Component', its working fine.

Comment: You don't have to use connect function `export default CounterComponent;`